# Acessar vetor de struct dentro de uma struct em C

Tags: c, struct, estrutura-de-dados

Tenho o seguinte struct:

```
struct estoque{
    char descricao[50];
    Produto* vetor[TAM];
    int qtde;
};
```

E gostaria de acessar os dados que estão no vetor de produtos, até agora fiz da seguinte forma:

```
void estoque_imprimir(Estoque* e){
  printf("%d\n", e->qtde);
  printf("%s\n", e->descricao);

  // aqui é onde estou errando
  for(int i = 0; i < e->qtde; i++){
    printf("(%d, %s, %f)", e->vetor[i]->codigo, e->vetor[i]->descricao, 
  e->vetor[i]->preco);
  }
}
```

Mas estou confuso de que forma posso realizar essa operação.

Comment: `descricao` não fica dentro do vetor de produtos. Faz parte de `estoque` . Poste um programa completo

Answer (score 0):

De onde veio essa variável produto? , e você não precisa usar um vetor dentro da *struct* , pois o vetor será criado para a *struct* toda.

```
struct estoque
{
  char descricao[50];
  int Produto;
  int qtde;
};
struct estoque e[10];  /// Aqui um vetor para essa struct
```

Comment: É um exercício e a estrutura do struct já veio definida assim, apenas tinha que trabalhar em cima do mesmo.